# How can I add specific pages of a PDF file as backgrounds on different pages?

Tags: pdfpages, backgrounds

I want to add specific pages from a PDF as backgrounds to different pages in my LaTeX document, creating a new command for each desired image. How can I do this? I'm somewhat new and can't find how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Have you used the [`pdfpages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package before? If it's a small number of pages and you want to add custom text atop your background, you can use `\includepdf[pagecommand={My custom text}]{background.pdf}`. If you want something different, please edit your question to include additional details, such as whether you want to add text on top of your background, whether the text should span multiple paragraphs or even multiple pages, and what your end result should look like.

Comment: `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[page=4]{yourpdf}}}`?